# Get the OAuth of my device to my Chrome Custom Intent

Tags: android, google-signin, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to access a google page from my app that requires sign in. I use Chrome Custom Tabs to do this. Since this is an android device the user has already signed in via a gmail account, so my question is how can I make the Custom Intent to log in to that account automatically when it is launched?

If it helps, I can also implement a separate login for my app and store the user details there and can I export that data to the Chrome Custom Tabs?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of OAuth is to *avoid* storing users' credentials.

If you are looking to implement Google Sign-In, you *can* use Chrome Custom Tabs, but Google has a separate SDK for this purpose ([Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/)).

If you are intent on using Chrome Custom Tabs, I highly recommend using [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android), which handles most of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I have to show the user a web page that cannot be called via an API, so Custom Tabs or WebView or Browser are my only choices. I tried using Custom Intent but for some reason it crashes when I start a download.

Comment: I fixed the download error. It was caused by my emulator which had no chrome installed and launched the Custom Tabs from default webview browser.